# Mongodb connection url not working in AWS Glue Connection screen

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am trying to connect to mongodb from AWS glue connection screen and getting error

tried various url's

mongodb://server1:2066,server2:2066,server3:2066/*dbname*.*collection*?authMechanism=PLAIN&authSource=&external

mongodb://server1:2066,server2:2066,server3:2066/?authMechanism=PLAIN&authSource=&external

Error in AWS Glue connection output in cloud watch

```
Check that your connection definition references your Mongo database with correct URL syntax, username, and password.
Exiting with error code 30
```

It works in Glue job with same VPC/Subnet/Security groups

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext, SparkConf
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
import time
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session

job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)


mongo_uri = "mongodb://_SERVER_1:2066,_SERVER_2:2066,_SERVER_3:2066/?authMechanism=PLAIN&authSource=$external"

read_mongo_options = {
    "uri": mongo_uri,
    "database": "_DB_",
    #"authMechanism": "PLAIN",
    #"authSource": "$external",
    "collection": "_collection_",
    "username": "****",
    "password": "***",
    "partitioner": "MongoSamplePartitioner",
    "partitionerOptions.partitionSizeMB": "10",
    "partitionerOptions.partitionKey": "_id",
    "inferSchema": "false"
}
    
logger = glueContext.get_logger()
logger.info("Connecting...")
s3_location = 's3://_bucket_/output/'


dynamic_frame = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(connection_type="mongodb",
                                                            connection_options=read_mongo_options)
print("Connected!")
```